# Problem with modifying image pixel by pixel in Pillow Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm running python3 and my code is:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("image.png")
pixels = im.load()
for x in range(im.width):
    for y in range(im.height):
        pixels[x, y] = (50,50,50)

im.show()
```

The code seems to be correct according to the docs but it throws this error:

```
File "file.py", line 7, in <module>
    pixels[x, y] = (50,50,50)
TypeError: color must be int or single-element tuple
```

How can a color be a single integer?

Comment: is it a grayscale image by any chance?

Comment: It probably means your image mode is `'P'` which uses a palette to associate pixel values with colors.

Comment: @Marat No it's rgb, and the resolution is 256x256

Comment: You code is working with a random image I have on my computer. Did you install Python 10 by chance? Have you tried any other images?

Comment: The error indicates that it's not `'RGB'` so you're mistaken.  You can use `convert` to change the mode to be sure.  PNG is a very flexible format that can be either paletted or RGB.

Comment: @MarkRansom I tried ```im.convert("RGB")``` but it didn't help

Comment: `convert` doesn't convert the image in-place, it returns a converted copy which you must use instead.  Try `im = Image.open("image.png").convert("RGB")`

Comment: Thanks ```im = Image.open("image.png").convert("RGB")``` solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what is happening, but I have some code that will change a single pixel:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("filepath")

def set_pixel(image, pixel, rgb):
     pixels = list(image.getdata())
     width, height = image.size
     pixels = [pixels[i * width:(i + 1) * width]for i in range(height)]
     pixels[pixel[0]][pixel[1]] = rgb
     data = np.array(pixels, dtype=np.uint8)
     new_image = Image.fromarray(data)
     return new_image

#set_pixel: the first input is an image object, the next is the pixel you want to change, the third is the rgb you want to set it to
img = set_pixel(img, [0, 0], (0, 0, 0))
```

And also some code that will change multiple pixels at once.
(It's just faster, but more confusing and harder to use)

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("filepath")

def set_pixels(image, pixelz, rgbs):
     pixels = list(image.getdata())
     width, height = image.size
     pixels = [pixels[i * width:(i + 1) * width]for i in range(height)]
     for x in range(0, len(pixelz)):
       pixels[pixelz[x][1]][pixelz[x][0]] = rgbs[x]
     data = np.array(pixels, dtype=np.uint8)
     new_image = Image.fromarray(data)
     return new_image
     
set_pixel_pos = [[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0]]
set_pixel_rgb = [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)]
img = set_pixels(img, set_pixel_pos, set_pixel_rgb)
```